# Excel Range to list using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, excel

I am struggling to convert an excel range to a list that I can iterate over. I'm trying to read string values from range D8 up to  the last row in same column. Example code shown below:

```cs
Excel.Worksheet sht = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
int lastrow = sht.Range["D1000"].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row;

List<String> names = sht.Range[sht.Cells[8, 4], sht.Cells[lastrow, 4]].Value;

foreach (String person in names)
{
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox(person);
}
```

I get an error `An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[*,*]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`

I been reading all day about lists and arrays and cant seem to find a simple solution that I understand . I'm still new to C# and most discussions and questions about excel & arrays have complex code spanning multiple lines. Coming from python its a shocker something relatively trivial can be a major challenge. How can I get this working quite simply?

Comment: The `.Value` object isnt't a `List<string>`. So this fails. The already answered question should solve it.

Comment: @Oliver Oh i didnt see that one. Thanks, saved me more hours